# Undefined method when calling Helper methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following helper

```
module AvatarHelper

    # Todo: set a defatul profile-image-path
    DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH = "http://image_here"

    def avatar_path(user, size = 24)
        ..
    end

    def get_facebook_profile_pic user, size
        ..
    end

    def get_gravatar_path user, size
        ..
    end

end
```

When I try to call the helper method in controller, it results in the following error:

> undefined method `avatar_path' for AvatarHelper:Module

Here is my controller for reference:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @dashboard = Dashboard.new(current_user)
        puts AvatarHelper.avatar_path(current_user)
    end
end
```

When I reference other helpers, I see they don't need to reference the helper elsewhere.

```
module TitleHelper

    SITE_TITLE = 'My Site'
    TITLE_SEPARATOR = ' · '
    DESCRIPTION_CHARACTER_LIMIT = 140

    def title(*parts)
        parts << SITE_TITLE
        provide(:title, parts.compact.join(TITLE_SEPARATOR))
    end
end
```

I can then just add the title method directly in the view.

```
<% title 'myPage' %>
```

Comment: make it a class/module method if you want to use it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def self.avatar_path(user, size = 24)
        ..
end
```

you are calling instance method add `self` before mthod will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Module methods cannot be invoked directly. They should be included in the class to invoke. That's why they are called mixins(they can be mixed with others).

Here you can include the module in your controller.

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  include AvatarHelper

   def index
        @dashboard = Dashboard.new(current_user)
        puts avatar_path(current_user)
   end

end
```

Comment: To your answer, I was referencing other helper and i see they don't need me to include helper. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your helper.

```
module AvatarHelper
           extend ActiveSupport::Concern
```

Now you can directly call your method by name like

```
puts avatar_path(current_user)
```

Comment: All the three answers so far from #coderVishal #SachinR and @kamesh works for my case but I wonder which one is the correct way. :) Thanks

Comment: The answer i posted, I learned from the book "Agile Development in Rails 4" by Sam Ruby, so you can be assured that this is the correct and proper way, I dont say that the other answers are wrong

Comment: And also if you think any of the answers helped, up vote them , and select one as your answer