# undefined ApplicationHelper method in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside application_helper.rb I have the following

```
module ApplicationHelper

def my_method(number)
  .....
end
```

In my view when I try to call the method

```
alt="<%= my_method(i)%>"
```

I am getting an error

```
undefined method `my_method' for #<#<Class:
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For using helpers you always need to include them to the desired location.

Comment: Do you @AfsaneFadaei? I've _never_ specifically included one for a view -  only controllers, the behaviour for which has changed in [Rails 5](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) - I thought they were included by default in views?

Comment: Some answers that might be of use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478697/undefined-method-when-calling-helper-methods-in-rails) @Petran

Comment: try in the console to include the helper: > include ApplicationHelper. Then call your method to see the output > helper.my_method , and then see if the method throw error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the helper in the controller for that view by adding this line in the controller for the view.

```
include ApplicationHelper
```